# Else statement is executed even the condition is met

Tags: php

This is 2 forms and 2 actions when the submit button is hitted. First form asks account name and checks if the captcha code is fine. When both are fine it proceeds the user to the next form that asks him 2 questions so he can retrieve his password. Code is executing fine but i got a problem. When everything is ok: account exists, captcha is fine, both questions are ok, when user hits submit button at the second form the else statement from 1st action is executed again but the forms continious fine and he got his password e mailed. Any help would be appriciated :)

```
if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']){
if($_POST['lostpassword']=='account' AND ($_POST["captcha"])&&$_POST["captcha"]!=""&&$_SESSION["code"]==$_POST["captcha"]) {

connectdb($CONFIG['dbdbname'], $CONFIG['dbaddress'], $CONFIG['dbuser'], $CONFIG['dbpass']);

$postusername = $_POST['account'];
$postusername = antiinjection($postusername);

$result = mssql_query (sprintf(SELECT_USER_FULLINFO, $postusername));
$rows=mssql_num_rows($result);

if($rows>0) {
    $rows=mssql_fetch_assoc($result); 
    extract($rows);
    $error = 2;
} else {
    echo "Account doesn't exist.<br>";
    $error = 1;
}       
}
else { 
       echo '<script language="JavaScript">
             alert("Wrong Verification code. Please try again.");
             </script>';
     }
}
```

The form:

```
<form name='lostpassword' action='index.php?page=lostpassword' method='post'     onsubmit='return checkform1()' autocomplete='off'>
    <table CELLSPACING=0 BORDER=0 CELLPADDING=0 align=CENTER>
        <tr>
            <td width=200>
                Account
            </td>
            <td>
                <div align=right>
                    <input type=text maxlength=14 name=account>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign=middle>
                Verification Image  <img src=\"captcha.php\">
            </td>
            <td>
                <div align=right>
                    <input type=text maxlength=4 name=captcha>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <div align=center>
        <BR>
        <input type=hidden name=lostpassword value='account'>
        <input type=submit name=Login value='   Submit   '>
    </div>
</form>
```

Nexti Action:

```
if($_POST['lostpassword']=='email' ) {

$error = 3;
$postusername = $_POST['account'];
$postanswer1 = $_POST['answer1'];
$postanswer2 = $_POST['answer2'];
$postusername = antiinjection($postusername);
$postanswer1 = antiinjection($postanswer1);
$postanswer2 = antiinjection($postanswer2);

connectdb($CONFIG['dbdbname'], $CONFIG['dbaddress'], $CONFIG['dbuser'], $CONFIG['dbpass']);

$result = mssql_query (sprintf(SELECT_USER_FULLINFO, $postusername));
$rows=mssql_num_rows($result);

if($rows>0) {
    $rows=mssql_fetch_assoc($result); 
    extract($rows);

    $postanswer1 = encrypt($postanswer1);
    $postanswer2 = encrypt($postanswer2);
    $answer1 = '0x' . substr(bin2hex($answer1), 0, 32);
    $answer2 = '0x' . substr(bin2hex($answer2), 0, 32);

    if($answer1!=$postanswer1) {
        echo "Answer to security question #1 is incorrect.<br>";
        $error = 2;
    }
    if($answer2!=$postanswer2) {
        echo "Answer to security question #2 is incorrect.<br>";
        $error = 2;
    }
} else {
    echo "Account doesn't exist.<br>";
    $error = 1;
}

}
```

Form for this action:

```
<form name='lostpassword' action='index.php?page=lostpassword' method='post'      onsubmit='return checkform2()' autocomplete='off'>
<table CELLSPACING=0 BORDER=0 CELLPADDING=0 align=CENTER>
<tr>
    <td  width=200>
        Security Question #1
    </td>
    <td>
        <div align=right>
            {$quiz1}
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Security Answer #1
    </td>
    <td>
        <div align=right>
            <input type=text maxlength=32 name=answer1>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Security Question #2
    </td>
    <td>
        <div align=right>
            {$quiz2}
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Security Answer #2
    </td>
    <td>
        <div align=right>
            <input type=text maxlength=32 name=answer2>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<div align=center>
    <BR>
    <input type=hidden name=lostpassword value='email'>
    <input type=hidden name=account value='{$postusername}'>
    <input type=submit name=Login value='   Submit   '>
</div>
</form>
```

Email code:

```
if($error==3) {

$newpassword = mt_rand(1000000,9999999);
$newpassword = md5($newpassword);
$newpassword = substr($newpassword, 0, 15);
$encnewpassword = encrypt($newpassword);
echo '<br>';

mssql_query(sprintf(UPDATE_PASSWORD, $encnewpassword, $account));

if($CONFIG['email']==0) {
    echo "<strong>Your password has been reseted to...</strong><br>{$newpassword}<br><br>";
} elseif($CONFIG['email']==1) {
    sendemail($CONFIG['emailsmtp'], $CONFIG['emailuser'], $CONFIG['emailpass'], $CONFIG['emailaddress'], $CONFIG['servername'], "Lost Password", $email, $account, $newpassword, $ssn, "<strong>Your password has been reseted and sent to your email.</strong>");
}

}
```

Comment: Did you have to include your entire site ?

Comment: I am tired reading this :(

Comment: put complete post file as continuous code

Comment: Its the content of index.php it appears when user select lost password button

Comment: where is password email code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course else statement from first condition is executed, because the else statement verify the negation of first if that is:

```
if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']){

}
else {

}
```

And when user submit the second form, obvious enter in first condition.

You could fix this by, for example adding another name value to the submit input button like:

```
<input type='submit' name='LoginAct1' value='Submit' />
<input type='submit' name='LoginAct2' value='Submit' />
```

and then you will verify what form data was sent.

```
if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && isset($_POST['LoginAct1']) ){
     //blah blah
}

if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && isset($_POST['LoginAct2']) ){
     //blah blah
}
```

Comment: It's not nice to take the vote and accepted answer :)), but it's your decision.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the first action's "if condition" as follows:

```
if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && $_POST['lostpassword']=='account'){
    //rest of the code
}
```

Then your code will be working fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i tried the code in the 1st answer and it worked fine!